# How to access native USB port of Arduino Due on Synology NAS?

Tags: serial, arduino-due, avrdude, linux, programmer

I would like to flash my Arduino Due from my Synology DS218+ NAS which runs on an Intel 64bit Linux-derivate platform. Previously, I was able to flash a Mega 2560 from this NAS via avrdude and currently, I am able to flash an Arduino Due via bossac through the Due's programming port. The port is registered as /dev/ttyACM0 (as was the Mega 2560) after I installed the necessary usbserial kernel module.
However, the native port is not detected likewise, or rather it is deregistered immediately:

```
[8336388.471865] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[8336388.613119] Got empty serial number. Generate serial number from product.
[8336388.685041] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[8336389.331596] usbcore: deregistering interface driver cdc_acm
```

The programming port shows up like this:

```
[8338189.956730] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[8338190.100022] usb 1-2: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
[8338190.615513] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[8338190.621705] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[8338190.628534] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

Is there anything I need to install in addition to the usbserial kernel modules to get the native port working?

P.S.: I know that the programming port is more stable, but it is also rather slow with its 115200 bps. Uploading a sketch that just takes up 50% of the Due's flash memory takes almost a minute, and if you want to see the effects of code changes, this is quite time consuming.

Comment: how is this an Arduino related question?

Comment: @jsotola: I think part of the question is whether the Due needs two different drivers for the programming and native port respectively or whether the Due needs some kind of configuration on the native port to be detected properly. Furthermore, when I posted the same question on stackoverflow as I thought it is (also) a operating system question, it was downvoted to -2 within a few hours because it was seen as an Arduino related question.